# “session has expired” error - after clicking a button with webdriver in IE8

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java, ie8

After clicking a button in my application with webdriver, it gives me “sorry..your session has been expired” in IE8 and I am unable to proceed but I am able to do it manually.

Now to proceed with webdriver automation I have to login into my application manually first, then it doesn't give me that session expired error.

Problem is my application only works on IE. This issue is a showstopper now.

Now I am confused. Is this an IE issue (some cookie handling) or webdriver provides some support for session or cookie handling?

I am using selenium version selenium-java-2.24.1 and IE driver version IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.3.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried seeing what's different yet?  Are the http requests significantly different between when selenium navigates through the pages as opposed to when you do?  Have you checked for any security settings in IE that may be causing issues?

Comment: @LyndonVrooman:I checked url while navigating with both the ways (through webdriver and manually) ,url is same in both the cases.

I have already set security settings as mentioned in selenium docs for IE.
If still i am missing something or you can suggest me.Please lemme know.
Thanks Lyndon..

Comment: As per selenium docs here in  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver  I was trying to set "protected mode settings" but first thing its not mentioned there for Window xp and i am using Window XP.The second thing is on my machine i am not able to see any check box under tools-->internetOptions-->security.I think may be due to my office's security reasons.Now i am stuck how to do it.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade to the latest IEDriverServer: 4.43.xxx:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/
Also you can try both x86 and x64 versions.

Comment: I wouldn't advise anyone to use x64 IEDriverServer after I encountered the slow typing issue and read this horrifying root cause analysis https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21